# Podcast headphone monitoring

Tags: podcasts

I am setting up a medium podcast studio for 4 person recording, and I am wondering about the headphone monitoring.

Is it ok to just attach a headphone amplifier and put the mix in the earphones or will it be distracting to hear your own voice as high as the rest of the group?

Ideally I would route a subgroup to each of the phones, so you could do the mix yourself, but that seems unpheasable for such a project...

What do you think?

**Setup:**
4 Røde NT1A
Recording 4 tracks on Tascam DR-70D
4 Yamaha HPH100 headphones
Presonus HP 60 Headphone mixer (for future expansion)

Comment: What do you plan to have them hear in the headphones? If everyone is in the same room and you just want to have them listen to each other there is really no reason to use headphones.

Comment: Good question. They will be listening and commenting on soundclips and also I think there will be callers via skype. Depending on the number of studio participants.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not distracting at all. It’s often not necessary. The only real reason to use headphones for a conversation or interview is if you want other audio to be heard by the talent but not picked up by the microphones.

A basic headphone amp will work fine, but it should have separate volume controls for each person. Even with the same model headphone, different people will prefer different listening levels.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is only weird at first to hear yourself but you get used to it. The only reason it would be a problem is if there were a long latency between when they speak and when they hear themselves. But I would strongly suggest you buy a small mixing console so you can have a "program mix" and a "monitor mix" separate from each other.